# Indentation size with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

Tags: php, json

The php function [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) has an option to set indentation in the outputted json for a "pretty" version. This option is called:  `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

A minor pet peeve is that this feature uses 4 spaces in said indentation.

Is there is a way to make it use 2 spaces, instead of 4 or an efficient way to process the output to reduce the 4 spaces to 2, without it breaking any of the JSON keys/values which may have spaces in them?

Comment: That's a tent not a function.

Comment: That's awesome - I pasted the wrong link. Deleting comment and reposting... "I doubt it, but you could implement a custom function [like this one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#102091) and change the indentation that way"

Comment: thanks! (It was a nice tent)

Comment: Can give you a good price if you want one ;-) hope the function helped

Comment: i'm trying the function out, worried its going to be less efficient than the built in function so need to way it up against what is not really a major issue.

Comment: It will be less efficient

Comment: The rest of us are wondering what tent you were looking at...

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```php
$data = ['some' => 'data'];
$json = preg_replace_callback(
    '/^(?: {4})+/m',
    function($m) {
        return str_repeat(' ', 2 * (strlen($m[0]) / 4));
    },
    json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
);
```

For tabs, change the lambda's return to:

```php
str_repeat("\t", strlen($m[0]) / 4);
```